# Show that an element $ A \in G $ is uniquely determined by its restriction to $ Q $

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $ Q $ be the set $ \{(1,1),(-1,1),(-1,-1),(1,-1)\} $ in $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $ and be
$
G=\left\{A \in \mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{R}) \mid A(Q)=Q\right\} .
$

Thus $ G $ consists of those invertible matrices which map the vertices of a square in the plane to themselves. You may use without proof that $ G $ is a group.

Show that an element $ A \in G $ is uniquely determined by its restriction to $ Q $.

Hint: Choose an appropriate basis of $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $. Argue with respect to this basis using the representation matrix.

Problem: What does "uniquely determined" mean in this context?

First approach / idea:
If you were to look at it like a linear algebra problem, I would first use the standard basis on $R^2$ and consider the group rule as a mapping rule so that a mapping matrix can be formed, but then what would be the interpretation to this in our context of considering a group?

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: "Uniquely determined" means that each two matrices $A$ and $B$, which agree on $Q$ are equal: $A=B$. For the explicit matrixes of $G$ see, for example, [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2833997/representations-and-classes-of-square-group-d4).